# Coding convention of using a string literal

Tags: c++

I know there is no specific rule of how to use or declare a string literal, like for example in my class, I want to use "MyName" string literal, and its the only class that will use it, for example,

```
// CFoo.h
class CFoo
{
public:
    CFoo();
    ~CFoo();
    void printString();
}

// CFoo.cpp
CFoo::CFoo()
{
}

CFoo::~CFoo()
{
}

void CFoo::printString()
{
    std::cout << "MyName" << std::endl;
}
```

Now I want that "MyName" will have a descriptive name placeholder, like NameLiter or something like that. Should I use define preprocessor, or declare it as global in cpp as const std::string? Or should I make a private member variable and initialize it in the ctor initializer list?

Thanks!

Comment: It all depends.. See, if each class `instance` is going to have a separate name, then make it a private variable initialised during construction. If it is the same name being shared amongst all class `instances`, make it static and private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making it a `private static const char*` in CFoo would satisfy your requirements.